# What does 'Environment: production' mean for python-eve?

Tags: python, flask, eve

I followed the quick start guide and created a simple Eve app. In the console, I saw below messages.

```
 * Serving Flask app "eve" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 ...
```

I checked the **Development / Production** section of the document but could find anywhere mentions the `Environment` setting. More specifically, I could not figure out:

- How does eve decide if the environment is in *development* or *production*?
- Besides the settings provided, does eve app apply different settings to a different environment?
- Can I change the **Environment** name from the settings? E.g. **Environment: docker-dev**.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#environment-and-debug-features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask comes with a built-in web server to allow you to test your work but it is not secure or robust enough to run a live system that will be exposed to the public. For that you should deploy your Flask app using a full-strength server. Instructions are available on the Flask website. Personally I like Gunicorn.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/